How to perform matthews_corrcoef in sklearn simultaneously for every column using a matrix?
I want to perform Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC) in sklearn to find the correlation between different features (boolean vectors) in a 2D numpyarray. What I have done so far is to loop through each column and find correlation value between features one by one.
Here is my code:
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
n_sample, n_feature = X.shape
rff_all = []
for i in range(n_feature):
    for j in range(i + 1, n_feature):
        coeff_f_f = abs(matthews_corrcoef(X[:, i], X[:, j]))
        rff_all.append(coeff_f_f)
rff = np.mean(rff_all)

As I have a huge dimension of 2D numpyarray, it seems to be really slow and impractical. What is the most efficient way to perform this kind of operation simultaneously without using the loops?
Edit: I then come up with this idea but it is still pretty slow.
from more_itertools import distinct_combinations
all_c = []
for item in distinct_combinations(np.arange(X.shape[1]), r=2):
    c = matthews_corrcoef(X[:, item][:, 0], X[:, item][:, 1])
    all_c.append(abs(c))


Short of multiprocessing, you are not going to get any speed ups from what you are already doing.

@James Can we use one matrix multiply with the same matrix but transpose matrix and then perform the matthews_corrcoef to get a single matrix and take the half of values from the diagonal to upper part or from the diagonal to lower part then take the mean of those values?

You can use numba to speed up the computing, e.g:
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.njit
def _fill_cm(m, c1, c2):
    m[:] = 0

    for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
        m[a, b] += 1


@numba.njit
def mcc(confusion_matrix):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875660/992687

    tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
    fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
    fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]

    x = (tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn)
    return ((tp * tn) - (fp * fn)) / sqrt(x + 1e-6)


@numba.njit
def get_all_mcc_numba(X):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    confusion_matrix = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype="float32")

    out = []

    for i in range(columns):
        c1 = X[:, i]
        for j in range(i + 1, columns):
            # make confusion matrix
            c2 = X[:, j]
            _fill_cm(confusion_matrix, c1, c2)
            out.append(abs(mcc(confusion_matrix)))

    return out

Benchmark:
from timeit import timeit
from math import sqrt

import numba
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef


def get_all_mcc_normal(X):
    n_sample, n_feature = X.shape
    rff_all = []
    for i in range(n_feature):
        for j in range(i + 1, n_feature):
            coeff_f_f = abs(matthews_corrcoef(X[:, i], X[:, j]))
            rff_all.append(coeff_f_f)
    return rff_all

@numba.njit
def _fill_cm(m, c1, c2):
    m[:] = 0

    for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
        m[a, b] += 1


@numba.njit
def mcc(confusion_matrix):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875660/992687

    tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
    fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
    fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]

    x = (tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn)
    return ((tp * tn) - (fp * fn)) / sqrt(x + 1e-6)


@numba.njit
def get_all_mcc_numba(X):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    confusion_matrix = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype="float32")

    out = []

    for i in range(columns):
        c1 = X[:, i]
        for j in range(i + 1, columns):
            # make confusion matrix
            c2 = X[:, j]
            _fill_cm(confusion_matrix, c1, c2)
            out.append(abs(mcc(confusion_matrix)))

    return out

# make 2000 x 100 0-1 matrix:
np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2000, 100), dtype="uint8")

assert np.allclose(get_all_mcc_normal(X), get_all_mcc_numba(X))


t_normal = timeit("get_all_mcc_normal(X)", number=1, globals=globals())
t_numba = timeit("get_all_mcc_numba(X)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"{t_normal=}")
print(f"{t_numba=}")

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):
t_normal=4.352220230008243
t_numba=0.008588693017372862


You can further speed up the computing using numba multiprocessing:
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def get_all_mcc_numba_parallel(X):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    num_cpus = numba.get_num_threads()

    # for each thread, allocate array for confusion matrix
    cms = []
    for i in range(num_cpus):
        cms.append(np.empty((2, 2), dtype="float32"))

    out = np.empty(shape=(columns, columns), dtype="float32")

    # make indexes for each thread
    thread_column_idxs = np.array_split(np.arange(columns), num_cpus)

    for i in range(columns):
        c1 = X[:, i]

        for thread_idx in numba.prange(num_cpus):
            for j in thread_column_idxs[thread_idx]:
                if j < i + 1:
                    continue

                c2 = X[:, j]
                _fill_cm(cms[thread_idx], c1, c2)
                out[i, j] = abs(mcc(cms[thread_idx]))

    out2 = []
    for i in range(columns):
        for j in range(i + 1, columns):
            out2.append(out[i, j])

    return out2

Benchmark (using only numba/numba+parallel versions):
import perfplot

np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2000, 100), dtype="uint8")

assert np.allclose(get_all_mcc_normal(X), get_all_mcc_numba(X))
assert np.allclose(get_all_mcc_numba(X), get_all_mcc_numba_parallel(X))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2000, n), dtype="uint8"),
    kernels=[
        get_all_mcc_numba,
        get_all_mcc_numba_parallel,
    ],
    labels=["single", "parallel"],
    n_range=[100, 250, 500, 750, 1000],
    xlabel="2000 rows x N columns",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)

Creates this graph:


For matrix with 10_000 rows and 10_000 columns:
t_numba=782.5051075649972            (~13 minutes)
t_numba_parallel=215.43611432801117  (~3.5 minutes)


Thank you so much for an insightful approaches. I have a related question. Suppose I have a matrix X and an output class let's say y. How can I calculate the MCC between every feature of X with y and take the mean value simultaneously and faster as well?

@Erwin I suggest to make a new question here on stackoverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78412549/how-to-perform-matthews-corrcoef-in-sklearn-simultaneously-between-every-column

Do you know how to speed up this process in my recent question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78419689/faster-way-to-perform-xor-operations-between-two-2d-numpy-ndarray-with-memory-ef

I believe you could also use pdist:
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
np.abs(pdist(X.T, matthews_corrcoef)).mean()
0.10476190476190476

Although will be considerably slower than numba as this will have another loop for absoluteness and another one for summation.
