Faster way to perform XOR operations between two 2D numpy.ndarray with memory efficiency
I want to perform the XOR operations between two 2D numpy.ndarray by saving the memory usage. For each row of u, I want to perform the XOR operation to every row of v and so on. For example, if u has dimension (8,10) and v has dimension (6,10), the result will end up with a dimension (48, 10).
Here is a simple example to demonstrate that:
import numpy as np

u_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]])

v_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]])

#First this is what I tried:
u_reshaped = u_values[:, None, :]
v_reshaped = v_values[None, :, :]
xor_result = u_reshaped ^ v_reshaped
xor_results = xor_result.reshape((-1, xor_result.shape[2]))

This is what I get a result with dimension (48, 10)
[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True  True False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True  True False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True False False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False  True False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False False  True  True False]]

It worked just fine with this toy example. However, when I applied it with two big 2D numpy.ndarray I ran out of memory. I even tried to use the np.packbits function to see if I can save some memory:
u_values_packed = np.packbits(u_values, axis=1)
v_values_packed = np.packbits(v_values, axis=1)
result_packed = u_values_packed[:, None, :] ^ v_values_packed[None, :, :]

result_packed = result_packed.reshape((-1, result_packed.shape[2]))
result_unpacked = np.unpackbits(result_packed, axis=1)[:, :u_values.shape[1]]

When I performed my real use case, I got this error:

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 959. GiB for an array with shape (2788, 1813, 203769) and data type uint8

I even tried to perform the XOR operations using chunk by storing temporary results into a memmap file which takes the max_memory_usage in GB as one of its parameters. Here are my codes:
import math
def calculate_number_chunk(u_value, v_value, max_memory_usage):
    dim_u = u_value.shape[0]
    dim_v = v_value.shape[0]
    column_dimension = u_value.shape[1]

    chunk_size_square = (max_memory_usage * math.pow(1024, 3)) / column_dimension

    return math.floor(math.sqrt(chunk_size_square)), dim_u, dim_v, column_dimension

def chunk_xor(u_value, v_value, max_memory_usage, memmap_filename):
    chunk_size, dim_u, dim_v, col_dimension = calculate_number_chunk(u_value, v_value, max_memory_usage)
    # create memmap file
    a = np.memmap(memmap_filename, dtype='bool', mode='w+', shape=(dim_u * dim_v, u_value.shape[1]))
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for i in range(0, dim_u, chunk_size):
        for j in range(0, dim_v, chunk_size):
            # u matrix
            u_chunk = u_value[i:i + chunk_size]
            # v matrix
            v_chunk = v_value[j:j + chunk_size]
            res_xor = u_chunk[:, None, :] ^ v_chunk[None, :, :]
            res_xors = res_xor.reshape((-1, res_xor.shape[2]))

            end += res_xors.shape[0]
            a[start:end, :] = res_xors
            start = end

    return dim_u, dim_v, chunk_size, col_dimension

I can then manipulate it from the memmap file as follow:
dim_u, dim_v, chunk_size, col_dimension = chunk_xor(u_value=u, v_value=v, max_memory_usage=max_mem_usage, memmap_filename=memmap_file_directory)
                                                               
# read results from the mem-map file using chunk size
xor_memmap = np.memmap(memmap_file_directory, dtype='bool', mode='r', shape=(dim_u * dim_v, u.shape[1]))
start = 0
end = 0
for idx in range(0, dim_u * dim_v, chunk_size):
    end += chunk_size
    xor_results = xor_memmap[start:end, :]
    start = end
    # xor_results will process for further from here ...
                                                                    

I am so curious if there is a better and/or a faster way to avoid converting to 3D numpy.ndarray before the XOR operation? If not, how can I speed up this kind of operations using chunk? I can perform up to 512 GB RAM.
Any reccommendation will actually help.

I am not sure to follow. Apparently you understand broadcasting. But, on another hand, you seem to think that it is a temporary array that takes this memory. It is not. Your expected result is the one that needs hundred of GB. Those 3D array (the ones I can see in partial code) either do not (u_reshaped just use half a GB (which is already a lot for me, but apparently, not for you). Or are just the same as the result. xor_result, before reshaping, has indeed shape (2788, 1813, 203769), and uses 959 GiB. But those are the same 959 GiB it will still use after reshaping to (5054644, 203769)

@chrslg It ran out of memory when i processed it entirely at one. However, it worked fine if i cut it into a chunk and process it in terms of the maximum memory I set. I just want to know if there is a better way to achieve this faster with less memory usage.

Yes, because you no longer compute the result in memory. In your version (which might be the only thing to do. I am not criticizing it. Just trying to understand why you imply that this has something to do with intermediary 3D array) xor_result (whether 2D or 3D, it really doesn't matter, it is the same data) never exist in memory entirely. You didn't change just the method. You've also change the outcome: you no longer compute xor_result (and again, xor_result, whatever its shape, take 959 GiB, so that is probably the right thing to do to renounce having it as an array)

My only point (but maybe it is just I who misread your message) is not about what you do, and whether it works. It is about the fact that you seem to think that the problem is because of the existence of xor_result as a, temporarily, 3D array. But .reshape doesn't allocate nor free any memory. it is just the same as your final 2D array result. It doesn't matter that it has a 3D shape for a while. The only thing that matters is that the wanted result cannot fit in your memory.

Yeah in fact, I want to perform it entirely at one but due to the memory issue, i need to do like this. However, the whole results that I will get, I still need to perform it further line by line.

Why do you actually need to store that somewhere? Even the fastest SSD are many orders of magnitude slower than CPU cache (and XOR operations) and at least 1 order of magnitude slower than the RAM in term of throughput (>=2 for the latency). This seems a huge wast of resources to me (especially for basic XOR). Can't you compute a on the fly? Recomputing a several times is far cheaper than storing it (both in RAM and on SSD). XOR are very very cheap nowadays.

@JérômeRichard Can you propose a simple solution for this? Many you can do better than my case.

Well, I do not know what computation is done on a because it is not provided in the question. This is the part described as "xor_results will process for further from here" (which matters the most). So far, I can just advise you to replace a[start:end, :] = res_xors with process(res_xors) where process is the magical function doing the further processing missing in the question ;) . Please explain what is this process if you cannot do that.

@JérômeRichard Actually, the whole result that I will get from the result of XOR will process and write to a file line by line. That is why it does not bother me to do the chunk. I just wonder if there is a way more faster.

@JérômeRichard a is a numpy temp file from memap file.

Ok, but this is what makes things slow. Computing chunks should take a small time compared to the line a[start:end, :] = res_xors simply because storage device are significantly slower than RAM (and the CPU). You can remove the line to see the difference. Can't you write directly the value in binary (with packbits) rather than bools which waste 88% of the slow storage device throughput (which is certainly already the bottleneck)? It will certainly significantly help. Note that packing+unpacking is useless for speed if in the end the written values are unpacked.

@JérômeRichard I precise my short question again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421427/most-efficient-way-to-perform-xor-operations-between-two-matrices-by-using-less
