Most efficient way to perform XOR operations between two matrices by using less memory
I want to perform the XOR operations between two 2D numpy.ndarray by saving the memory usage. For each row of u_values, I want to perform the XOR operation to every row of v_values and so on. For example, if u_values has dimension (8,10) and v_values has dimension (6,10), the result will end up with a dimension (48, 10).
Here is an example:
import numpy as np

u_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]])

v_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]])

#What I have tried so far:
u_reshaped = u_values[:, None, :]
v_reshaped = v_values[None, :, :]
xor_result = u_reshaped ^ v_reshaped
xor_results = xor_result.reshape((-1, xor_result.shape[2]))

This is what I get a result with dimension (48, 10)
[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True  True False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True  True False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True False False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False  True False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False False  True  True False]]

The final result that I want is a list of rows which each row contains the index of the True values
final_results = [np.nonzero(row)[0] + 1 for row in xor_results]

It worked pretty fine with a small example. However, for my real case, I encounter a very huge 2D numpy.ndarray with u_values with the size of (2788, 203769) and v_values with the size of (1813, 203769)
I ran out of memory for the XOR operations:

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 959. GiB for an array with shape (2788, 1813, 203769) and data type uint8

I was wondering if there is a more straight forward and faster way to speed up this process by handling this kind of problem in order to get the list of the desired result as mentioned above (i.e. final_results) without computationally so expensive?

The index of the True value? A lot of rows have more than 1 True, and some of them have none.

@user2357112 for example: [False True True False] -> [1 2]. Only the index of the True value is retained. When some of them have None just exclude them.

In expectation, your final result is going to have 515 billion True entries. Each index would need to be at least 3 bytes (realistically 4 bytes), for nearly 2TiB of storage. How are you planning to store that much data?

This is the same issue than in the previous question : the output is too large and the main question is thus what you do with the result (so to find ways not to store the output somewere and compute it directly on the fly). In fact, storing the value in binary (like in the previous post) is actually more compact than finding the indices (at least based on the provided input).

@nneonneo please see my previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78419689/faster-way-to-perform-xor-operations-between-two-2d-numpy-ndarray-with-memory-ef

@JérômeRichard I still need to find the index of the True values with the result on the fly but just to store it first to the hard disk.

Is this a stress test for your disk, or why are you doing this?

@nocomment I won't do this for nothing. It is related to my project :(

Well if you refuse to tell us about that, we likely won't be able to do anything here.

@nocomment Well, my project is about finding the binary features that differentiate between two big matrices. So it related to the XOR operations for the binary features datasets. That is why I tried to store index of the True values at the end.

@Erwin I don't understand your response to nneonneo. If on average 50% of the values are true, the output array will be absolutely huge. If the final product doesn't fit in memory, it seems like it doesn't matter that none of the previous steps fit in memory either. Is this assumption that 50% of values are True correct?

Perhaps you could save memory by using a pairwise hamming distance calculation, rather than storing all values that disagree.

@NickODell The final result can indeed be written into a text file directly without storing. Do you have any idea or quicker way to write it directly into a text file?

@NickODell BTW, which pairwise distance is equivalent to XOR operation?

Binary to text conversion tends to be slow. Actually often slower than storing data on a fast storage device. Besides, "written into a text file directly without storing" does not mean anything to me: where the text file is supposed to be written if it is not stored somewhere?

@JérômeRichard Actually, I really don’t know which one is faster. Like in my previous approach I used memmap file which is still a slow process. Furthermore, for the list of final_results, I will also further process it one by one.

@Erwin Hamming distance is equivalent to the number of True bits after x ^ y.

"for the list of final_results, I will also further process it one by one" - And why don't you just do that right away, without storing the whole final_results?

@nocomment I still could not perform the XOR operations to get the xor_results as I wanted. How can I do it right away? One way to do it is to process line by line which is too slow.

The xor part would not be line by line and would be fast, faster than your final_results = [np.nonzero ...] which is really line by line anyway.

I'd write a generator function for this.
def linewise_xor(u_values, v_values):
    for v_value in v_values:
        xor_results = u_values ^ v_value
        yield [np.nonzero(row)[0] + 1 for row in xor_results]

This will generate chunks of your results relating to the shape of u_values, but won't generate anything too big for your memory to handle.  You can process these sequentially.

Thanks for your answer. I already tried this one already but since I have many lines to process it became very slow.

@Erwin But that's because of the slow looping over the xor results with the np.nonzero stuff, right? The xor-ing itself is fast, no? Then maybe you shouldn't have asked about the xor but just about that actual slow part.

The question you've asked butts you up against the physical, mathematical limitations of your computer.  Everyone's asking what the surrounding process is because there may be a way around needing all that data in memory; but without that context - we can't give you the 2TB of storage you'd need to do what you've asked.  There's no way around the math.
