How to perform matthews_corrcoef in sklearn simultaneously between every column using a matrix X and and output y?
I want to calculate the Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC) in sklearn between every column of a matrix X with an output y. Here is my code:
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
n_sample, n_feature = X.shape
rcf_all = []
for i in range(n_feature):
    coeff_c_f = abs(matthews_corrcoef(X[:, i], y))
    rcf_all.append(coeff_c_f)
rcf = np.mean(rcf_all)

It worked pretty good here but as long as I have a very big matrix with many features, calculating them by looping through one feature at a time is pretty slow. What is the most effective way to perform this simultaneously without using the loop to speed up the calculation process?

Tweaking my previous numba answer:
from math import sqrt
from statistics import mean
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef


def get_all_mcc_normal(X, y):
    n_sample, n_feature = X.shape

    rcf_all = []
    for i in range(n_feature):
        coeff_c_f = abs(matthews_corrcoef(X[:, i], y))
        rcf_all.append(coeff_c_f)

    return mean(rcf_all)


@numba.njit
def _fill_cm(m, c1, c2):
    m[:] = 0

    for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
        m[a, b] += 1


@numba.njit
def mcc(confusion_matrix):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875660/992687

    tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
    fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
    fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]

    x = (tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn)
    return ((tp * tn) - (fp * fn)) / sqrt(x + 1e-6)


@numba.njit
def get_all_mcc_numba(X, y):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    confusion_matrix = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype="float32")

    out = []

    for i in range(columns):
        _fill_cm(confusion_matrix, X[:, i], y)
        out.append(abs(mcc(confusion_matrix)))

    return sum(out) / len(out)


X = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
)
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])

# make 2000 x 100 0-1 matrix:
np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2000, 100), dtype="uint8")
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=2000, dtype="uint8")

assert np.allclose(get_all_mcc_normal(X, y), get_all_mcc_numba(X, y))

t_normal = timeit("get_all_mcc_normal(X, y)", number=1, globals=globals())
t_numba = timeit("get_all_mcc_numba(X, y)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"{t_normal=}")
print(f"{t_numba=}")

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):
t_normal=0.08777441698475741
t_numba=0.00017813200247474015


EDIT: Combining the functions + making the functions using parallelization:
from math import sqrt

import numba
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef


@numba.njit
def _fill_cm(m, c1, c2):
    m[:] = 0

    for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
        m[a, b] += 1


@numba.njit
def mcc(confusion_matrix):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875660/992687

    tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
    fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
    fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]

    x = (tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn)
    return ((tp * tn) - (fp * fn)) / sqrt(x + 1e-6)


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_mcc_numba_X_y_parallel(X, y):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    num_cpus = numba.get_num_threads()

    # for each thread, allocate array for confusion matrix
    cms = []
    for i in range(num_cpus):
        cms.append(np.empty((2, 2), dtype="float32"))

    out = np.zeros(shape=(columns, columns), dtype="float32")

    # make indexes for each thread
    thread_column_idxs = np.array_split(np.arange(columns), num_cpus)

    out = np.empty(shape=columns, dtype="float32")
    for thread_idx in numba.prange(num_cpus):
        for i in thread_column_idxs[thread_idx]:
            _fill_cm(cms[thread_idx], X[:, i], y)
            out[i] = abs(mcc(cms[thread_idx]))

    return sum(out) / len(out)


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_mcc_numba_X_parallel(X):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    num_cpus = numba.get_num_threads()

    # for each thread, allocate array for confusion matrix
    cms = []
    for i in range(num_cpus):
        cms.append(np.empty((2, 2), dtype="float32"))

    out = np.empty(shape=(columns, columns), dtype="float32")

    # make indexes for each thread
    thread_column_idxs = np.array_split(np.arange(columns), num_cpus)

    for i in range(columns):
        c1 = X[:, i]

        for thread_idx in numba.prange(num_cpus):
            for j in thread_column_idxs[thread_idx]:
                if j < i + 1:
                    continue

                c2 = X[:, j]
                _fill_cm(cms[thread_idx], c1, c2)
                out[i, j] = abs(mcc(cms[thread_idx]))

    out2, cnt = 0.0, 0
    for i in range(columns):
        for j in range(i + 1, columns):
            out2 += out[i, j]
            cnt += 1

    return out2 / cnt


def calculate_mcc(X, y):
    return calculate_mcc_numba_X_y_parallel(X, y), calculate_mcc_numba_X_parallel(X)


X = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ],
    dtype="uint8",
)
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype="uint8")

# first run of calculate_mcc() will compile the jitted functions
print(calculate_mcc(X, y))


EDIT 2: To compare normal/numba version of cumputing mcc_X_y:
from math import sqrt

import numba
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef


@numba.njit
def _fill_cm(m, c1, c2):
    m[:] = 0

    for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
        m[a, b] += 1


@numba.njit
def mcc(confusion_matrix):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875660/992687

    tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
    fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
    fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]

    x = (tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn)
    return ((tp * tn) - (fp * fn)) / sqrt(x + 1e-6)


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_mcc_numba_X_y_parallel(X, y):
    rows, columns = X.shape

    num_cpus = numba.get_num_threads()

    # for each thread, allocate array for confusion matrix
    cms = []
    for i in range(num_cpus):
        cms.append(np.empty((2, 2), dtype="float32"))

    out = np.zeros(shape=(columns, columns), dtype="float32")

    # make indexes for each thread
    thread_column_idxs = np.array_split(np.arange(columns), num_cpus)

    out = np.empty(shape=columns, dtype="float32")
    for thread_idx in numba.prange(num_cpus):
        for i in thread_column_idxs[thread_idx]:
            _fill_cm(cms[thread_idx], X[:, i], y)
            out[i] = abs(mcc(cms[thread_idx]))

    return sum(out) / len(out)


def calculate_mcc_X_y(X, y):
    n_sample, n_feature = X.shape
    rcf_all = []
    for i in range(n_feature):
        coeff_c_f = abs(matthews_corrcoef(X[:, i], y))
        rcf_all.append(coeff_c_f)
    rcf = np.mean(rcf_all)
    return rcf


X = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ],
    dtype="uint8",
)
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype="uint8")

print(calculate_mcc_numba_X_y_parallel(X, y))
print(calculate_mcc_X_y(X, y))

Prints:
0.17457431554794312
0.1745743121887939


Thanks for your answer again. I was just wondering if you can combine those two calculations together (i.e. the calculation between features in X and calculation between every feature in X and y into a new function and compare the time?

@Erwin If I understand you right, you want to compute mcc(X[:, i], X[:, j]) and mcc(X[:, i], y) in one loop?

Yeah absolutely. I edited my question.

@Erwin I'd just combine the functions. See my edit (I also made the function to use parallelization)

I still got the errors as I mentioned above when I tried to call calculate_mcc(X, y)

@Erwin What errors do you get? calculate_mcc is just normal Python function (without numba.njit). Also, it expects 2D array X and 1D array Y (both 0-1 arrays). I've updated my answer with complete program.

I got the errors like this: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/blob/master/practice_dictionary/errors_numba.docx I dont know why... I used python 3.10

I added my code here: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/blob/master/practice_dictionary/another_example.py I tested with the real dataset (I also uploaded in the same directory) but I got the errors as I mentioned earlier. Can you please check it?

@Erwin Make sure you supply uint8 as X and y, eg X_subset.astype("uint8"). Also, seems y is -1/1 -> make it 0/1 or change how confusion matrix is computed.

Ahh yeah. I see the problem. Up voted alr :)

Can you check your function calculate_mcc_numba_X_y_parallel(X, y) again? I tested it with the benckmark method it did not provide the same output. I saw inside your code you declared variable out two times. Here is my updated source code and updated dataset: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/blob/master/practice_dictionary/another_example.py

@Erwin I've updated my answer - the results should be identical (sans floating imprecision)

Why sqrt(x + 1e-6) is so sensitive? When I deleted 1e-6 the answer is far from the same.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Erwin With 1e-6 you make sure you don't have division by zero and NaN as a result

Okay I see. One last question, is there a way we can integrate matthews_corrcoef into your codes to get the exact same result by avoiding the manual written codes as suggested?
